# Test all strings are in resource files

Tags: c#, resources, localization

I'm in the process of moving text in my application into resource files; I'd like a quick way of testing to see at a glance if any text has not yet been replaced. One way to do this (I thought) was to replace all the strings in my resource file with a different string of the same length, XXX, for example.

Is it possible to override ResourceManager.GetString to perhaps read the original string and replace it with X's of the same length? Should I create a different language resource file with hand-replaced X's and then switch my system language?

I know this won't get every instance as not all text is always immediately apparent (crashes, error dialogs etc) but it might be a good way of testing the majority.

Do people have some thoughts/ideas?

**Edit:**
I ended up finding [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2011/01/27/sudo-localize-amp-amp-make-me-a-sandwich-free-pseudolocalizer-class-makes-it-easy-for-anyone-to-identify-potential-localization-issues-in-net-applications.aspx) which has made it easy to see the obvious text that hasn't yet been replaced by resource files, although I'm still after tips about text in code! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just backup that ResourceStrings file then replace them all with XXX by hand if you want a quick way to see what you have, With copy paste it will take you no time at all.

Also you could try search your files looking for anywhere you have something like .Text = "  though this is going to bring up unwanted results and miss some too.

I did this a while back myself and to be fair the best way to do it is just take the unpleasant option and waste some time, go through it line by line and find everything that should be a resource string. It sucks and its boring but its better to do the job properly rather than having some code in resource strings, some as hardcoded text etc.